# gcc openmp tasks do not work

Tags: gcc, task, openmp

I have already used OpenMP with "pragma omp for" loops and wanted to try OpenMP tasks now.
But a simple program, which should run 2 tasks parallel does not seem to work.
Did I misunderstand the use of tasks or what is wrong here?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<omp.h>

//ubuntu 12.04 LTS, gcc 4.6.3
//g++ test_omp.cpp -fopenmp

int main()
{
 #pragma omp parallel
 {
  #pragma omp single
  {

      #pragma omp task
      {
          while(true) 
          {
           usleep(1e6);
           #pragma omp critical (c_out)
            std::cout<<"task1"<<std::endl;
          }
      }

      #pragma omp task
      {
          while(true) 
          {
           usleep(1e6);
           #pragma omp critical (c_out)
            std::cout<<"task2"<<std::endl;
          }
      }

  }
 }
}
```

The output is:
task1
task1
task1
.....

So the second task is not running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the OpenMP spec:

> When a thread encounters a task construct, a task is generated from
> the code for the associated structured block. The data environment of
> the task is created according to the data-sharing attribute clauses on
> the task construct, per-data environment ICVs, and any defaults that
> apply.
>
> *The encountering thread may immediately execute the task, or
> defer its execution.* In the latter case, any thread in the team may be
> assigned the task. Completion of the task can be guaranteed using task
> synchronization constructs. A task construct may be nested inside an
> outer task, but the task region of the inner task is not a part of the
> task region of the outer task.

(emphasis mine)

The way I read this: A single thread starts executing your `single` section. It reaches the `task` directive, at which point it may decide to either run the task itself, or give it to another thread. The problem occurs when it decides to run the task itself - it never returns.

I'm not quite sure why you have `task`/`single` in your example though. What you want to do seems like a case for `omp parallel sections` instead:

```
int main()
{
 #pragma omp parallel sections num_threads(2)
 {
      #pragma omp section
      {
          while(true)
          {
           usleep(3e5);
           #pragma omp critical (c_out)
            std::cout<<"task1"<<std::endl;
          }
      }
      #pragma omp section
      {
          while(true)
          {
           usleep(5e5);
           #pragma omp critical (c_out)
            std::cout<<"task2"<<std::endl;
          }
      }
 }
}
```

Comment: I thought a openmp task is always some kind of "spawn" or "fork" and the thread which encountered this task continues his work. But I was wrong.